# AppResources, dynamically finding variables

Tags: c#, database, mvvm, windows-phone-8, resources

I am developing a windows phone app using MVVM, and I want to use AppResources as a database for string, and that later enables me to localize the app. I have a loading popup where I display some tips.

So my database is something like

- tip_1      Remember to Run
- tip_2      Look out
- tip_3      And so on

I then want in my code to set the variable that is bounded with a new tip every time the loading screen is displayed.
So my question is how do I do this smart.

I right now use a switch case, that randomly takes a number, and then displays the tip. But that means every time I add a new entry to my database, AppResources. I have to update the switch. I would like to search in the AppResources, since dynamic variable names is no possible.

I was thinking something like this pseudocode

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int TipMax = Convert.ToInt32(AppResources.TipCount);
int i = rnd.Next(1, TipMax);
BoundVariable = Resources(String.Concat("Tip_",i.ToString());
```

But I have not been able to do it, Anybody have a solution?

**Extra**

I found the [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class, that also exist in Windows Phone, but cannot get that to work.

**Note**
The correct answer below, You should remmeber to ser minimum value for Random().Next(min,total); Just FYI :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`ResourceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class like this with the [`GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/d17ax2xk%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method:

```
var total = int.Parse(AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString("tip_total"));
// generate random number
var number = new Random().Next(total);
var tip = AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString("tip" + number);
```

This would assume that you had a resource named, "tip_total" that contains the total number of "tips" that you've stored. You could also just iterate through to "count" them all as well until `GetString` returns `null` (which it does when the resource isn't found).

Replace `AppResources` above with the name of the resource file name you have in your phone application.